# Get class name each input that typing is being

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want after keyup on input change `background-color` input into class `box`, but in following code change `background-color` all inputs, i can not change class name. How can fix it without change class name and use id, by closest.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/S4wL9/

```
$('input').live('keyup', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var class_show = '.' + $('.box').closest('.box').find('input').attr('class');
    $(class_show).css('background-color', '#999');
});
```

Comment: It might help if you explain what you're trying to accomplish in a little more detail? You want certain boxes to turn gray when you type in any box? Is that right?

Comment: do you want something like http://jsfiddle.net/S4wL9/4/

Comment: Step by step, please explain what you expect the user to do, and what you expect JavaScript to make happen. As it is, I have absolutely ***no*** idea what you want. I accept that English is (probably) not your first language, but please try and explain as clearly as you can what you want so we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try just changing the CSS property of the element.

```
$('input').live('keyup', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var class_show = '.' + $('.box').closest('.box').find('input').css('background-color', '#999');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// when any input is typed into
// turn the background-color of inputs
// with a parent of box gray

$("input").live("keyup", function(e) {
 e.preventDefault()
 $(".box input").css('background-color', '#999')
})
```

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do, sorry if that didn't help.

Comment: i'm sorry. it was my wrong. this is true link: http://jsfiddle.net/S4wL9/ . how is for it after keyup. with attr class name.